# Intercepting failing axios requests in nuxt

Tags: javascript, axios, nuxt.js

When making a request via axios that has an error response (according to axios docu any status outside of 2xx) the corresponding request method throws an error.
Not wanting to surround each and every request I make with generic catch blocks I finally figured out how to "get around" this with an interceptor:

```js
$axios.onError((error) => {
    return Promise.resolve(error);
})
```

probably corresponds to:

```js
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (error) {
    return Promise.resolve(error);
});
```

in vanilla axios.

My current question is: Is this considered to be bad practice? Is there a better way to to this? (Maybe something involving a config setting for validateStatus?) Also, since the status 2xx is explicitly stated I wonder whether also 1xx would throw an error.

The thrown error is especially unnerving because nuxt redirects to the error page every time I don't catch the error... So any help regarding that behaviour would be welcome too.

Comment: in nuxt you needed to use axios as middleware, or you prefer, you can use axios as plugin. Btw, for me the best way is use try catch api request inside my store/actions because each situation i can decide what is better to do. In real life, you can print a messages directlly to user from the api server, maybe some thing like invalid path, or the input can't be null, for me this way is most powerfull.

Comment: But it also means that I would have to repeat basic error handling for every single request.

Comment: yes, but if prefer, you can use a middleware for this. Or you can import axios from plugin, and get the error on each request.

Comment: create a new plugin/axios.js and import and configure axios in this file. Import this in your nuxt.config.js... You can use your code axios.interceptors.response.use(function (error) {
    return Promise.resolve(error);
}) inside this plugin file. This way work fine.

Comment: plase take a look https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors